# Assign a background image with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, background-image

I'm trying to assign an image to a label depending on the status of a checkbox, but it's not working

Javascript

```
        var myLabel = $('[id$=lbl]');
        var myCheckBox = $('[id$=chk]');
        if (myCheckBox.prop('checked'))
        {
            //myLabel.css('background-image', myLabel.data("image1"));
            myLabel.css({backgroundImage : myLabel.data("image1")});
            alert(myLabel.data("image1"));
        }
        else
        {
            myLabel.css({backgroundImage : myLabel.data("image2")});
            alert(myLabel.data("image2"))
        }
        alert(myLabel.css('background-image'));
```

The state of the checkbox is working well (true or false)
The alerts with myLabel.data("image1") and myLabel.data("image2") returns the url of the images [url(../images/active.png) no-repeat;   and url(../images/inactive.png) no-repeat;]

no matter how you assign the value

```
            myLabel.css('background-image', myLabel.data("image1"));
```

or

```
            myLabel.css({backgroundImage : myLabel.data("image1")});
```

the label it is still retaining the first assigned image at the moment of the load page. So the label is always with active image. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: what is the value of `myLabel.data("image1")`

Comment: I'd imagine the issue is with the url of the images being incorrect. A better method is to put the images in CSS classes and then just change the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem

As I said in my question I was assigning the image like this  ***url(../images/active.png) no-repeat*** but the css property was wrong. Instead of using the backgroundImage or background-image, finally I used the "background" and period. the "no-repeat" part was causing a problem.

```
myLabel.data("image1") = "url('../images/active.png') no repeat;";
myLabel.css("background" : myLabel.data("image1"));
```

Or you can do this also if you want to use the background-image property.

```
myLabel.data("image1") = "url('../images/active.png')";
myLabel.css("background-image" : myLabel.data("image1"));
myLabel.css("background-repeat" : "no-repeat");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
   var myLabel = $('[id$=lbl]');
    var myCheckBox = $('[id$=chk]');
    if (myCheckBox.prop('checked'))
    {


        myLabel.removeClass('active')
        myLabel.addClass('inactive');

    }
    else
    {
        myLabel.removeClass('inactive')
        myLabel.addClass('active');
    }
```

and define the css like

```
.active{background-image:url(../images/active.png) no-repeat; }
.inactive{background-image:url(../images/inactive.png) no-repeat;}
```